# Counting occurrences based on timeline?

Tags: excel

My data consists of data like so:

```
2014-01-01 14:31:50 John
2014-01-01 14:41:51 Jacob
2014-01-01 19:01:51 Locke
2014-01-01 19:11:49 John
2014-01-01 19:21:51 John
```

I want to create a stacked bar graph that will show how many times a name occurs within that time frame. So as an example if I select the timeline as months, a bar for Janrary will be created with John having 3, and so on. Effectively something like this:

[image: graph]

The problem I'm having is that excel is trying to put the data together so it ends up looking like this:

[image: actual]

I'm not sure why it is clumping the entire contents of a column into one section. Do i have to specify how to represent the data somehow ? It would also be best if the process was dynamic (such that the data isn't processed and modified) as the data is obviously generating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to collate your information before proceeding to graph it, if you want it displayed visually in a way other than what the data is supplied in. This is all possible via a pivot table:

[image]

The above collation by year/month in the pivot table is achieved by selecting the `Date` field, then clicking on Group (under the Data ribbon), and selecting both Year and Month:

[image]

Then you can extract the relevant information through a pivot and graph from there:

[image]

Above the collation was performed by month for a specific year (2014).

Comment: You seem to be expanding on my approach without really adding any information, by just adding a column for year and month (which I mentioned, too). What is the purpose of your post? You don't even pick up on why the OP's data is not fit for charting. Isn't that a bit blunt?

Comment: @teylyn: You mention "You'll find resources for grouping by year and month on the web, if you just search", to which I've added how that could be done using my year/month column approach.

Comment: my only suggestion would be to do this in a pivot chart instead (same exact steps as you listed) which would allow you create a chart that is linked to the pivot data that is already grouped.

Comment: @guitarthrower: Great suggestion. I wanted to add separate data to display the categories in Mon/Year format. If the OP is only graphing a single year, then that would be the way to go.

Comment: It would do multiple years no problem. It would simply repeat each month, then have a category below that for each year.

Comment: Again: the real problem of the question has been addressed in a different answer. This answer just extends the basic principles provided in that other answer.

Answer (score 2):

Excel can only create a chart based on numeric values to plot on the Y axis. Your source data does not provide any numeric data, but just dates and text.

You can build a pivot table to create a count of names for each date and then create a pivot chart off that.

It is not clear if the date and time are in one column or two, so the screenshot below shows date and time in column A, spliced out date (using =int(a2)) in column B, spliced out time (using =MOD(A2,1)) in column C and Name in column D.

Create a pivot table from that list. Drag the "date" field into the rows, the "name" field into the columns and the "name" field (again) into the values area to create a count of names per date.

Click "Pivot Chart" on the Pivot Tools ribbon to create the chart and format to your liking. You can group the pivot table by month name, if you add a column to the source data for month. These concepts have been discussed hundreds of times. You'll find resources for grouping by year and month on the web, if you just search.

[image]